# How to prevent removal of "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder when IIS not installed

Tags: asp.net, abyss

I'm using a 3rd party web server to host ASP.Net applications on a Windows 10 computer that does NOT have IIS installed.  After most Windows 10 updates it appears that the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder (v4.0.30319) gets removed and my web server does not have permissions to create it.

My understanding is that the user can run aspnet_regiis.exe, which registers a particular version of ASP.Net with IIS, and this folder will be created but if IIS isn't installed this utility doesn't create the folder.  If I manually create the Temporary ASP.NET Files directory and restart my web server then things work fine.

How can I prevent this folder from being removed??

Comment: seems odd that the tool relies on a folder it can't create. Bit of a design flaw, no?

Comment: If by tool you mean ASP.NET, yes, odd.  If you are referring to the 3rd party web server, it is running as a service so it depends entirely on the account that the service is running on.  I am using the Local Service account, which should be an Admin on the machine but for some reason it doesn't have permission to create the folder.  What would be best is if the folder never gets removed to begin with.

Comment: no I meant the abyss webserver. IIS can create the folder, and that uses ASP.NET, and abyss cannot create the folder, when using ASP.NET. This suggests ASP.NET is not the problematic component. Although possibly simply it's a case of permissions - double check that the local service account actually has the folder permissions needed. As for not removing the folder, not sure you can really interfere with the windows update process!

Comment: Thanks AD, it's not abyss' fault - it can only do what the user the service is running as can do.  According to the MS documentation I found, Local System account should be allowed to create this folder, and IO permissions on the folder above it seems to corroborate.  It is a mystery to me why MS has made this so unwieldy.